# AWS Amplify Storage.put() Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I created an amplify react native app and attached a S3 Bucket manually, when I called the function "Storage.put()" it displayed this error.

[image]

This is my code.

[image]

Auth Configuration

[image]

Comment: have you signed in with user who has access to upload to the s3 bucket ?

Comment: Yes, cognito user pool has the access to upload to the s3 bucket.

Comment: yes but i mean did you use         const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password); before doing the upload (you need to do it one time in early initialization)

Comment: Yes, this step is done.

Comment: i think what is left is either the storage config

Comment: I have rechecked the authentication, there was some error. Thank you @FadiAboMsalam

Answer (score 0):

Add `await` for `Storage.put()`:

```
let data = await Storage.put('cheque/cheque_1', blob)
```

Comment: Still not working.